# Storing PGTs and PGTIOUs CAS generates

Tags: cas

Jasig CAS (Central Authentication Service) generates PGTs and PgtIOUs for proxy services. I would like to keep track of these tickets in a central location. CAS seems to store these things in memory. Is there a way to store them in a DB?

My plan is to store these tickets in a DB and create a web service to serve multiple proxy applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS stores all its tickets, including proxy tickets in whatever ticket registry is configured.  The default ticket registry is implemented with a `ConcurrentHashMap`, so yes, by default they are stored in memory. However, CAS has several other ticket registry implementations including a `JpaTicketRegistry`,  which stores tickets in a DB.

There are complete instructions on how to configure CAS to use a `JpaTicketRegistry` at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JpaTicketRegistry